# Rewrite URL if specific parameter exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url like this:  `website.co.uk/search.php?a=category&b=test&c=test`

I want to rewrite search.php to /search/ and the variable 'a' only if it exists.

So that the url would redirect to: `website.co.uk/search/category/?b=test&c=test`

If the url was:  `website.co.uk/search.php?b=test&c=test`

Then this should redirect to `website.co.uk/search/?b=test&c=test`

Currently I am using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/(.*?)/?$ search.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /search\.php\?a=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?search\.php$ /search/%1? [L,R=301]
```

If I enter the url `website.co.uk/search.php?a=category&b=test&c=test`

It redirects to `website.co.uk/search/category`

How do I add the remaining parameters to the end of this URL?

So that it looks like `website.co.uk/search/category/?b=test&c=test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?a=([^&\s]*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/? [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php(?:\?a=([^&\s]*)&(\S+))?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/?%2 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php(?:\?(\S+))?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/?%1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)/?$ search.php?a=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the urls are not redirecting... also are you able to update your answer for multiple parameters, for example `website.co.uk/search.php?a=category&b=test1&b=test2&c=test3&c=test4&c=test5` where `b` and `c` can be added as many times as possible

Comment: urls with `a` are redirecting fine, urls without the `a` parameter are redirecting to the correct url but showing error 404 Object not found! page

Comment: `website.co.uk/search/?b=test`

Comment: Both your previous answer and your current answer are working fine, just one last problem - if the url has `a` without any other parameters it should redirect to `website.co.uk/search/category` but currently it redirects to `website.co.uk/search/?a=category`